# obtain radio interface layer on mobile website not application

Tags: mobile, geolocation, wap, cellid

I was using IP2location dlls to get the user's location but i realised that it doesn't work on mobile websites. 
I read about getting the users location through the cell ID information and i was wondering if this can be used through mobile website on a server level or it has to be on the device level in an application ?

http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/post-images/080312-rilcode.cs.txt

```
string cellid = RIL.GetCellTowerInfo();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is either

1. mobile devices implementing the html5 location extensions (via javascript)
2. Network operators sending through the cellid in some HTTP header to certain
   sites.  (Either yours or some site you redirect to to return you the info)